# JQuery each issue - div wrapped twice

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

I'm trying to solve an issue that I'm facing with JQuery about each.
I have a list of items (class .list) that I need to target and wrap in a div (class .wrap). It works if the list but when there is a second one the loop wrap twice the list in the new div.

The idea is that every time there is a class called list, the loop wrap that specific class in a div called wrap.

Here is the code

HTML

```
 <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
      <div class='list'>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
      <div class='list'>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JQuery

```
jQuery(".parent").each(function () {
  jQuery(".list").wrap("<div class='wrap'></div>");
});
```

This is the result with the error.
The class list is wrapped twice as you can see from the example below.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="wrap"><div class="wrap"><div class="list">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
      </div></div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="wrap">
          <div class="list">
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are not selecting the list is the parent Your selecting all the parents, you loop, you select all the lists in the page, and wrap. So you select all the lists once for each parent.

Answer (score 1):

You want to select the list in the parent, not select all lists

```
jQuery(this).find(".list").wrap()
```

Comment: awesome, it worked! 
Thank you so much (: